# instance has no attribute __getitem__

Tags: class, web2py

I am working on a life simulation game based on the game of life in web2py.  I have two objects which contain several arrays for the various attributes of the organisms in each space on the grid. I received this error  LifeSpace instance has no attribute '**getitem**' on the line containing this code                 nxt[i][j] = processNeighborsEmpty (i, j, cur)

am I referencing the object instance improperly?

```
ROWS = 60
COLS = 60
GENERATIONS = 100
DELAY = 0.5

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class LifeSpace :
    def __init__(self):
        self.genus = []
        self.species = []
        self.tribe = []
        self.hunger = []
        self.wounds = []
        self.age = []
        self.genus = initGrid (COLS, ROWS, self.genus)
        self.species = initGrid (COLS, ROWS, self.species)
        self.tribe = initGrid (COLS, ROWS, self.tribe)
        self.hunger = initGrid(COLS, ROWS, self.hunger)
        self.wounds = initGrid(COLS, ROWS, self.wounds)
        self.age = initGrid(COLS, ROWS, self.age)  

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

def initGrid(cols, rows, array):
    for i in range(rows):
        arrayRow = []
        for j in range(cols):
            arrayRow+= [0]
        array += [arrayRow]
    return array

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def printGen(cols, rows, array, genNo):
    return("Game of Life -- Generation " + str(genNo + 1))
    for i in range(rows):
       for j in range(cols):
            if array.species[i][j] == 0:
                return(" ")
            elif array.species[i][j] == 'weed':
                return("3")
        return("\n")

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def processNeighborsEmpty(x, y, array):
    for j in range(y-1,y+1):
        for i in range(x-1,x+1):
            if not(i == x and j == y):
                if array.genus[i][j] == "plant" :
                    if array.age[i][j] == "adult" :
                        array.species[x][y] = array.species[i][j]
                        array.genus[x][y] = array.genus[i][j]
                        array.age[x][y] = "seed"
                        return array[x][y]

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def processNeighborsPlant(x, y, array):
    if array.age[x][y] != "adult" :
        if array.species[x][y] == "tree" :
            if array.age[x][y] == "sapling" :
                 array.age[x][y] = "adult"
            elif array.age[x][y] == "seed" :
                 array.age[x][y] = "sapling"
        elif array.age[x][y] == "seed" :
            array.age[x][y] = "adult"

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

def processNextGen(cols, rows, cur, nxt):
    for i in range(0,rows):
        for j in range(0,cols):
            if cur.genus[i][j] == 0 :
                nxt[i][j] = processNeighborsEmpty (i, j, cur)
            elif cur.genus[i][j] == "plant" :
                nxt[i][j] = processNeighborsPlant(i, j, cur)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
############################################################################
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

def index():
    thisGen = LifeSpace()
    nextGen = LifeSpace()

    thisGen.genus[25][25] = "plant"
    thisGen.species[25][25] = "weed"
    thisGen.age[25][25] = "adult"

    for gens in range(GENERATIONS):
        printGen(COLS, ROWS, thisGen, gens)
       processNextGen(COLS, ROWS, thisGen, nextGen)
        time.sleep(DELAY)
        thisGen, nextGen = nextGen, thisGen
    input("Finished. Press <return> to quit.")
```

Answer (score 0):

`nxt` is a LifeSpace object so you cannot reference to it using `[]` notation.

You need to use `nxt.attribute[x][y]` with the correct attribute. Maybe `nxt.genux[x][y]` is what you want to use.

Comment: I think I need to make an array of objects instead of objects which contain arrays.  Thank you.